# Way to prevent drush from eating custom profiles when updating core?

Tags: drush

I use drush make with a stub .make file to download a custom profile via git.

that profile has all of the modules I want all of my sites to start out with.

If I then go into that site, and run "drush up drupal", it will update core, and remove my custom profile.

This is not good, since all of the modules I downloaded with my install profile's make file get stuck into the profiles/myprofile/modules folder. This basically removes all of my installed contrib modules, and drush doesn't give me a way to put them any where else, so basically, I can't update core with drush.

Comment: You should post a bug report about this in the Drush issue queue. (http://drupal.org/project/issues/drush)

Comment: I did, though I was hesitant prior to posting here because I'm not entirely sure this isn't the intended behavior and I just don't understand it correctly.
http://drupal.org/node/1841676

Answer (score -1):

Consider to use [Aegir](http://community.aegirproject.org/). It supports this usecase.

Comment: You should consider expanding this post, and explaining how exactly Aegir might help in this case.